# Java how to add int in an array using loop

Tags: java

i cant seem to figure out the logic, here's my code

```
class stringrays {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[] numrays = {23, 6, 47, 35, 2, 14};
    int i;
    int z;
    int y;

    for (i=1; i < numrays.length; i++) {
        z = numrays[0] + numrays[i];
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

the above results shows 
29
70
58
25
37

which means that array 0 adds array 1, then array 0 adds array array 2 and so on.

what i want, is to add the first array 0 onto the next array and so on.. using a loop condition.

then get the average of the sum.

Comment: 1) What is your question?  2) Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Comment: "what i want, is to add the first array 0 onto the next array and so on" is unclear. could you please elaborate

Comment: Do you mean `int z = numrays[0]; /* in loop*/ z += numrays[i];` ?

Comment: no this isnt homework, its just an exercise i found on the web.

Comment: "first" array and "next" array ? there is only one array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `numrays[0]` and replace it with `z`

```
     int z =0;
for (i = 0; i < numrays.length; i++) {
        z = z + numrays[i];
        System.out.println("Sum:"+z);

    }
    System.out.println("Average:"+z/numrays.length);
```

Comment: im getting variable z might not have been initialized
            z = z + numrays[i];

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
int[] numrays = {23, 6, 47, 35, 2, 14};
int z = 0;

for (int i=0; i < numrays.length; i++) {
    z = z + numrays[i];
    System.out.println(z);
}
    System.out.println("Average : "+(z/numrays.length) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 23, 6 then 6 + 47 and so on you need to do:

```
for (i=0; i < numrays.length - 1; i++) 
{
   z = numrays[i] + numrays[i + 1];
   System.out.println(z);
}
```

Comment: and for finding average. z/numrays.length();

Answer (score 1):

Or the [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) way :

```
int sum = sum(asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic. Now you are printing sum of first and n-th number in array; old z value is lost. For sum in loop, use like `z = z + something`

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear what you need...

to add a value to the next position:

```
int[] numrays = {23, 6, 47, 35, 2, 14};

for(int i = 0; i < numrays.length - 1; i++) {
    numrays[i] += numrays[i + 1];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numrays));
```

to get the mean value:

```
int[] numrays = {23, 6, 47, 35, 2, 14};
double sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < numrays.length; i++) {
    sum += numrays[i];
}

double mean = sum / numrays.length;


System.out.println(mean);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "for each" loop, to sum the contents of the array and then find the average.

```
int sum = 0;

for(int each : numrays)
{
   sum = sum + each;
}

float average = each / numrays.length;
```